# Does AppsFlyer have development enviroment or sandbox?

Tags: appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

As titled, I am implementing AppsFlyer iOS SDK and integrating the service to our app.

But I do not see a way to distinguish the events coming from development environment or production.

Does it even exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked AppsFlyer Support, in short the answer is no.  And here is their official response:

> I will be happy to assist you.  The answer is no. We allow our
>   advertisers to use the production environment for both development and
>   store builds. The best way to separate tests is testing through
>   specific media source for tests versions. You may also download the
>   raw report and filter by media source / app version.

The best is to have two separate apps, one for dev and one for prod.

Comment: make sense, this is what I did

Comment: Is it possible to add same one app to appsflyer twice and use them as different environments?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Chan's comment, You need to give SDK app name and when you check in real-time data, you can filter SDK non-organic installs and then you can find our events triggered. Attached is the reference...

[Appsflyer SDK Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkHpS.png)